# MOOC Exercise 36 help: Loops, remembering and ending

Tags: java

i'm doing exercise 36 on MOOC for Java. I have to create an even and odd counter but my even and off counter is showing incorrect values. Everything works expect for this counter and i'm not sure why.

On another note it says the variables sum2 and average's initialiser '0' is redundant. My code still runs but why is it saying this only for sum2 and average and not all the other variables I initialised to 0 in the beginning?

Thank you!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Variables
    System.out.println("Type numbers: ");
    int numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = numbers;
    int minus = -1;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;
    int sum2 = 0;
    double average = 0;

    while (numbers >= 0) {
        numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        sum+= numbers;
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (numbers % 2 == 0 ) {
            even++;
        }else {
            odd++;
        }
    }

    if (numbers == minus) {
        int sum2 = sum + 1;
        double average = (double) sum2 / counter;
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum2);
        System.out.println("How many numbers: " + counter);
        System.out.println("Average: " + average);
        System.out.println("Even numbers " + even);
        System.out.println("Odd numbers " + odd);

    }
}
```

Comment: How isn't it working? What's your expected output and what's your current output? What's your input?

Comment: Hi, example I enter the numbers 2,2,4,7,-1. The result is showing there are 2 even numbers and 2 odd numbers. The answer should be there are 3 even numbers and 1 odd numbers. The result should not include the negative integer -1

Comment: Is it reading all the numbers in correctly? Try stepping through a debugger or printing the output you're reading

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't initialize `numbers` reading the first line. When you do that, the other counters aren't initialized correctly. Fix one,

```
int numbers = 0;
```

As for `sum2` being redundant, it is redundant<sup>**1**</sup> because `int sum2 = sum + 1;` should be `sum2 = sum + 1;` (or remove the `int sum2 = 0;`). You have **two** variables named `sum2`. Same issue with `double average = (double) sum2 / counter;` and `double average = 0;` there are two variables named `average`.

<sub><sup>**1**</sup>Here redundant redundancy is intentional.</sub>

Comment: I'm sorry I don't quite understand. So I have to keep int numbers = 0; in the beginning? If I do that then how will it take the user input when it says to "Type numbers:"?

Comment: I don't know how else to explain this: if you say `int numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());` then `int even = 0;` and `int odd = 0;` (one or the other) is incorrect; why? because it ignores the initial value of `numbers`. The easiest way to fix that is to only operate on the user's input **in** the loop.

Comment: Ahhhh I see that makes sense, thanks! I fixed that part however for the second part, I have changed int sum2 = sum + 1; to sum2 = sum + 1; as well as int double average = (double) sum2 / counter; to double average = (double) sum2 / counter; but it's still saying the variable for sum2 and average initialiser '0' is redundant. This gets fixed if I just remove the variables at the top where I initialised to zero from my original code but just wondering why this method works and the other one doesn't?

Comment: When you say `int sum` or `double average` you are **declaring** new variables. Here is a "car". It is has a value "Honda". Here is a second "car" (with a value "Toyota"). What is the value of "car"? How does the computer know which "car" you want?

Comment: Oh wait I changed int numbers = 0; at the beginning and now not only is the even and odd counters showing incorrect, all the calculations are also showing incorrect....I think it is taking the last input of -1 into the calculation when it shouldn't

Comment: Please disregard what I said, I found the solution. I will post the answer. Thank you everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, thanks everyone!

import java.util.Scanner;

public class draft {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

    int numbers = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int even = 0;
    int odd = 0;


    System.out.println("Type number: ");
        while (numbers >= 0) {
        numbers = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());
        sum = sum + numbers;
        counter = counter + 1;
        if (numbers >= 0 && numbers % 2 == 0 ) {
            even++;
        }
        if (numbers >= 0 && numbers % 2 != 0) {
            odd++;
        }
        }
    if (numbers == -1) {
        int sum2 = sum + 1;
        int counter2 = counter - 1;
        double average = (double) sum2 / counter2;
        System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
                System.out.println("The sum is " + sum2);
                System.out.println("How many numbers: " + counter2);
                System.out.println("Average: " + average);
                System.out.println("Even numbers " + even);
                System.out.println("Odd numbers " + odd);

    }
}
```

}